# How to make circles of given locations in D3 from an external JSON file?

Tags: json, d3.js

How to use the JSON data to make circles of the given "x" and "y" values and label the circle with the site name? Also, the radius of the circle should be equivalent to the amount given. The JSON file looks like this

{

"nodes": [

{
      "id": "site01",
      "x": 317.5,
      "y": 282.5
    },

{
      "id": "site02",
      "x": 112,
      "y": 47
    },

{
      "id": "site03",
      "x": 69.5,
      "y": 287
    },

{
      "id": "site04",
      "x": 424.5,
      "y": 99.5
    },

{
      "id": "site05",
      "x": 432,
      "y": 467
    },

{
      "id": "site06",
      "x": 567,
      "y": 482
    },

{
      "id": "site07",
      "x": 592,
      "y": 164.5
    },

{
      "id": "site08",
      "x": 782,
      "y": 397
    },

{
      "id": "site09",
      "x": 829.5,
      "y": 262
    },

{ "id": "site10",
      "x": 902,
      "y": 169.5}

],

"links": [

```
{"node01": "site01", "node02": "site08", "amount": 170},
{"node01": "site01", "node02": "site02", "amount": 100},
{"node01": "site01", "node02": "site03", "amount": 70},
{"node01": "site01", "node02": "site07", "amount": 50},
{"node01": "site01", "node02": "site09", "amount": 220},
{"node01": "site01", "node02": "site10", "amount": 350},

{"node01": "site02", "node02": "site03", "amount": 1000},
{"node01": "site02", "node02": "site04", "amount": 50},
{"node01": "site02", "node02": "site05", "amount": 60},
{"node01": "site02", "node02": "site08", "amount": 70},
{"node01": "site02", "node02": "site09", "amount": 80},

{"node01": "site03", "node02": "site06", "amount": 120},
{"node01": "site03", "node02": "site07", "amount": 130},
{"node01": "site03", "node02": "site09", "amount": 110},
{"node01": "site03", "node02": "site10", "amount": 120},
{"node01": "site03", "node02": "site04", "amount": 140},

{"node01": "site04", "node02": "site01", "amount": 50},
{"node01": "site04", "node02": "site05", "amount": 200},
{"node01": "site04", "node02": "site07", "amount": 210},
{"node01": "site04", "node02": "site09", "amount": 220},
{"node01": "site04", "node02": "site10", "amount": 190},

{"node01": "site05", "node02": "site06", "amount": 170},
{"node01": "site05", "node02": "site07", "amount": 150},
{"node01": "site05", "node02": "site08", "amount": 160},
{"node01": "site05", "node02": "site09", "amount": 130},
{"node01": "site05", "node02": "site10", "amount": 140},

{"node01": "site06", "node02": "site02", "amount": 800},
{"node01": "site06", "node02": "site07", "amount": 760},
{"node01": "site06", "node02": "site04", "amount": 780},
{"node01": "site06", "node02": "site09", "amount": 50},
{"node01": "site06", "node02": "site10", "amount": 80}
```

]
}

Comment: Did you try anything? Have you searched for examples online? Your question right now is just this: *"hey, I have this data and I want you guys to write a code that creates a chart with these specifications, for free"*. Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. I'm voting to close this as *"Questions asking us to recommend a tutorial"*.

Comment: What i did right now is making a bar graph, but that didn,t end up showing properly. Here is the code for that

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <style>

  .bar{
    fill: steelblue;
  }

  .bar:hover{
    fill: brown;
  }

    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
// set the dimensions of the canvas
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


// set the ranges
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// define the axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")


    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);


// add the SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// load the data
    d3.json("/Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/Lakshya/Downloads/data.json", function(error, data) {

        data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.id = d.id;
        d.x = +d.x;
    });

  // scale the range of the data
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.id; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x; })]);

  // add axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("x");


  // Add bar chart
  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.id); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.x); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.x); });

});

</script>

</body>
```